# Methods are not available from the class

Tags: android, timezone, method-missing

I have a project that I need to determine the Time Zone for.  The [TimeZone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset%28%29) class seems perfect for the task:

```
import java.util.TimeZone;

long tzo = TimeZone.getRawOffset();
```

However, The getRawOffset method is not available.  What am I not understanding?

Comment: Cannot instantiate the type TimeZone!?

Comment: You can't instantiate a `TimeZone` object directly because it is an abstract class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getRawOffset()` isn't static, so you can't call it on `TimeZone`. Instead you need an actual `TimeZone` object.

Probably something like:

```
int tzo = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
```

Comment: That's what I needed.  One question, based on the documentation, how would I know to access the method this way without trying a bunch of coding first?  Just want to be able to help myself better in the future.

Comment: @AndroidAddict if the method is `static` (like `getDefault()`), you can accesss the method via `ClassName.staticMethod();` Otherwise you have to first make your object (`ClassName c = new ClassName()`) then access the methods (using `c.methodName()`)